# HornetQ standalone and writing client code

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jms, hornetq

I am trying to run HornetQ server standalone. But i don't know how to do it, I downloaded hornetq-2.0.0.GA and started server using build.sh, But i am looking to start HornetQ server by java code, and the want to write one client code for writing message into the queue and further read from the queue.

Please help me in the following activities :

1. Want to know how to start HornetQ server Standalone by java code?
2. Want to write client code to write and read message into the queue.

Please remember i am not using JBoss or Tomcat server.

I will be very thankful, please do the needful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this part of the documentation can help you: http://hornetq.sourceforge.net/docs/hornetq-2.0.0.BETA5/user-manual/en/html/embedding-hornetq.html.